# Find an MST with maximum degree of some vertex, $u$.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

> Let a connected, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$. Find from the set of all MSTs, the MST, $T$ such that $d_T(u)$ is the highest ($d_T(u)$ is the degree of $u$ in the tree $T$).

Now, I thought about modifying Kruskal's algorithm: We sort the edges but with a priority to edges which include the vertex $u$. i.e. If there are two edges with the same weight then the edge containing vertex $u$ will be the first one.

Is that a valid solution?

Comment: Pleas, recall what is an MST (M=? S=Spanning T=tree?)

Comment: @JeanMarie, Minimum spanning tree.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing multi-criteria optimization. You need to decide what you want to optimise : either the weight of the tree, or the number of edges including the vertex $u$, or some combination of the two.

Your solution (or what I am getting from your description) provides, among the minimum spanning trees, the one in which has the biggest number of edges connected to $u$. This is not the same thing as the cheapest tree which holds all edges connected to $u$ (which you would get by starting Kruskal with already all edges adjacent to $u$).

To put it in other words, $\min \max \neq \max \min$

Am I clear enough?

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused - "among the minimum spanning trees, the one in which has the biggest number of edges connected to $u$" - isn't that what we want?

Comment: From your question, yes, I think it is.

Comment: Then, is my solution valid?